# What is the best way to transform unmerged cells to merged cells with Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file (top image) where I'm trying to essentially go from individual rows to merged rows and retain the order (bottom). I was thinking about using the groupby function but I don't really need to calculate anything just transform it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Code:

```
{'ID': {0: 80, 1: 80, 2: 80, 3: 80, 4: 80},
 'FINANCIAL CLASS RESTR': {0: 'BLUE CROSS',
  1: 'COMMERCIAL',
  2: 'COMMERCIAL',
  3: 'MEDICARE',
  4: 'COMMERCIAL'},
 'PAYOR RESTR': {0: 200001, 1: 100001, 2: 100009, 3: 400001, 4: 100060},
 'PLAN RESTR': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'LOCATION RESTR': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'EFFECTIVE FROM DATE': {0: 36526, 1: 34906, 2: 37469, 3: 36526, 4: 35065},
 'ACTIVE FLAG': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}}
```

[image]

Comment: are you reading in the dataframe in pandas and then want to write it to an excel file in that format?

Comment: Btw, merged cells are absolute hell in Excel. Highly suggest you don't do this. If you absolutely must use them, then I suggest openpyxl or xlsxwriter directly, not pandas.

Comment: @EmiOB yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @BigBen I personally wouldn't want the merged cells in Excel either but that's what I'm being tasked with.

Comment: I second @BigBen on using xlsxwriter, but writing excel formatting is a pain!

Comment: I <third> i don't see a use case of this being practical at all tbh

Comment: Thanks guys for your insight. I'm going to have the stakeholder rethink their request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 95% of the way there.

I just forced everything to be a string, built a list, then "\n".join()ed the string

This would not function as merged cells (merged cells give me chills), but would be human-readable in a similar way. Good luck.

```py
newdf = {
    "ID": [],
    "FINANCIAL CLASS RESTR": [],
    "PAYOR RESTR": [],
    "PLAN RESTR": [],
    "LOCATION RESTR": [],
    "EFFECTIVE FROM DATE": [],
    "ACTIVE FLAG": [],
}
for idval in df["ID"].unique():
    newdf["ID"].append(idval)
    q_val = df["ID"] == idval
    temp = df.query("@q_val").drop(columns="ID")
    for col in temp.columns:
        temp[col] = temp[col].fillna("")
        temp[col] = temp[col].astype("str")
        col_vals = []
        for x in temp[col]:
            col_vals.append(x)
        new_col_val = "\n".join(col_vals)
        newdf[col].append(new_col_val)
```